# Separate location for bin and conf folder in tomcat

Tags: tomcat6

Is there a way to change tomcat's conf folder location to something other than next to bin?

Original:

```
Tomcat - bin
         conf
         temp 
         lib
         webapp
FolderABC -
```

Expected:

```
Tomcat - bin
         temp
         webapp
FolderABC -
      - conf -- server.xml
             -- other files
```

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have only one possibility to do something like that without patching tomcat:

Use symbolic links to redirect the conf directory to your chosen directory:

If you use linux/macos something like this should work (not that much experience with windows, sorry)

```
mv conf FolderABC/conf
ln -s FolderABC/conf conf
```

Here is a listing of `/usr/share/tomcat6` from my fedora core system:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   4096 May 16 09:51 bin
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root tomcat   12 May 16 09:51 conf -> /etc/tomcat6
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root tomcat   23 May 16 09:51 lib -> /usr/share/java/tomcat6
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root tomcat   16 May 16 09:51 logs -> /var/log/tomcat6
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root tomcat   23 May 16 09:51 temp -> /var/cache/tomcat6/temp
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root tomcat   24 May 16 09:51 webapps -> /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root tomcat   23 May 16 09:51 work -> /var/cache/tomcat6/work
```